# BotBuilder - NLP with dispatch error No such host is known

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, dispatch, azure-qna-maker

I am new in using Bot Builder Framework. I was following this tutorial from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis.

I am using the code from GitHub(NLP-with-dispatch) and set up all the necessary requirements DISPATCH, Luis, Qnamaker, etc.

But after running the code using the bot emulator I got this error message.

"No such host is known".

[image]

BTW, I already updated the appsettings.json and bot config.
Anyone experience this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just created a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1083) for this, since the issue is so common.

With that sample, make sure that `LuisAPIHostName` in `appsettings.json` is just your LUIS region (ie `westus`).

Comment: To comment on mdrichardson's answer: the bot framework doc on dispatch, which covers that sample, is incorrect as of 19 July 2019. I've opened an issue to correct the docs [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1269) that explains it.