# Botframework publish to azure error. "No such host is known"

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, facebook-messenger

Hello i publish my bot to azure and have this error when i tested it on messenger. I downloaded the publish settings on my azure app and import it to the bot via Visual Studio. I have done this many times before but this is my first time publishing on the latest botframework design.

This bot is working fine on bot emulator including luis, qnaMaker and dispatch services.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105966/botbuilder-nlp-with-dispatch-error-no-such-host-is-known) but LuisAPIHostName in my appsettings.json is already set to region.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you
[image]
I can see the error because of this code

```
public class AdapterWithErrorHandler : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
{
    private const string ErrorMsgText = "Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.";

    public AdapterWithErrorHandler(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger, ConversationState conversationState = null)
        : base(configuration, logger)
    {
        OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
        {
            // Log any leaked exception from the application.
            logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception.Message}");

            // Send a catch-all apology to the user.
            var errorMessage = MessageFactory.Text(ErrorMsgText + exception.Message, ErrorMsgText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(errorMessage);
```

My appsettings:

```
   {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "MicrosoftAppId": "",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "",

  "DispatchLuisAppId": DispatchAppId,
  "DispatchLuisAPIKey": DispatchAPIKey,
  "DispatchLuisAPIHostName": "southeastasia",

  "LuisAppId": LuisAppId,
  "LuisAPIKey": LuisAPIKey,
  "LuisAPIHostName": "southeastasia",

  "QnAKnowledgebaseId": QnaMakerKBId,
  "QnAEndpointKey": QnaMAkerEndpointKey,
  "QnAEndpointHostName": QnaMakerEndpointHostName,
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

botServices:

```
 public class BotServices : IBotServices
{
    public BotServices(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        DispatchService = new LuisRecognizer(new LuisApplication(
        configuration["DispatchLuisAppId"],
        configuration["DispatchLuisAPIKey"],
        $"https://{configuration["DispatchLuisAPIHostName"]}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"),
        new LuisPredictionOptions { IncludeAllIntents = true, IncludeInstanceData = true },
        true);

        LuisService = new LuisRecognizer(new LuisApplication(
        configuration["LuisAppId"],
        configuration["LuisAPIKey"],
        $"https://{configuration["LuisAPIHostName"]}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"),
        new LuisPredictionOptions { IncludeAllIntents = true, IncludeInstanceData = true },
        true);

        QnaService = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
        {
            KnowledgeBaseId = configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
            EndpointKey = configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
            Host = configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
        });
    }

    public LuisRecognizer DispatchService { get; private set; }
    public LuisRecognizer LuisService { get; private set; }
    public QnAMaker QnaService { get; private set; }
}
```

Dispatch keys and endpoint
[image]

LUIS keys and endpoint
[image]

wwwroot
[image]

emulator with working luis,dispatch and qna(btw the error only appears when i click "trace" in the emulator)
[image]

> **UPDATE**

i changed appsettings to

```
  "DispatchLuisAPIHostName": "southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com",
```

and botservice to

```
            $"https://{configuration["DispatchLuisAPIHostName"]}"),
```

In messenger, it is now replying but detecting everything i type as "cancel" intent. I added a code to see intent and you can see the difference between emulator and messenger.

[image]

I typed the same thing on emulator but luis,qna and dispatch is working fine.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hi , have you configed "MicrosoftAppId" and "MicrosoftAppPassword" in appsettings correctly ?

Comment: Hi i tried adding tjhem just now to app settings. publish again but still same error. "No such host is known"

Comment: For others, [this is OPs GH question](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1722) and [this is a related PR discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1083)

Comment: Your code looks fine and it appears you're using the correct endpoint format. Can you verify that `LuisAPIHostName` is set to `southeastasia` in `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > App Service > Configuration`? Can you also verify that your deployed bot matches your local bot? You can view the files at `https://<yourBot>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT i have updated the question with images Sir Richardson

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT i change the hostname and bot service and now it is replying but detecting everything as cancel intent. This is working good in emulator so i really find it weird. i can give you the code in git if you want sir.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT think i should answer this by doing what i did in bot service and appsettings and ask another question about the consistent cancel intent?

Comment: Can you verify that `LuisAPIHostName` is set to "southeastasia" in `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > App Service > Configuration`? Can you also verify that your keys are correct in that same location in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Feel free to link to your code if that doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I tested your bot and it looks like the [the "help" intent is working fine](https://imgur.com/Fu4Cjwu)

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT I think this question is answered by what i did in the update. also i found a fix for the different intent detection in emulator and messenger. i think you will be interested Sir Richardson by how i fixed it but i have not posted the answer yet. here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625246/luis-only-picking-up-2-intent-when-published-in-azure-but-is-working-perfectly-i

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT also i can not found the app service for luis. only cognitive service. follow up question can you put luis,qna and bot service in one app service or app service plan? is it okay if they have individual app service or should i put them in one app service.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT i posted my answer to this question. can you explain why my answer work and why my posted code does not work sir? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625246/luis-only-picking-up-2-intent-when-published-in-azure-but-is-working-perfectly

Comment: @user10860402 Can you link to your code?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT i posted my code in the question here and also the answer. i also have it pushed in a private repo in github. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625246/luis-only-picking-up-2-intent-when-published-in-azure-but-is-working-perfectly-i

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT please tell my if you want to see full code in git or the code in question is enough. it is dawn now here and i have to sleep. will reply first thing when i wake up thank you Sir Richardson

Comment: @user10860402 I don't believe this one is solved (see my answer in your other issue). However, it's so related to the other issue that I will continue this conversation there.

Comment: @user10860402 I don't believe this one is solved (see my answer in your other issue). However, it's so related to the other issue that I will continue this conversation there.